# How to delete files in LINUX which are older than 30 days and are of specific extension *.pdf

Tags: linux, unix, directory, delete-file

I have a peculiar challenge, we have one directory where there is close to 15000 PDF files, and the file names also contain spaces (plus we have other config file which we are not supposed to touch).
I am trying to delete all the PDF files (Please note PDF file name has spaces) from this directory which are older than 30 days/1 month. how can I achieve this?

Comment: What do you mean by "older"?  It is easy to check modification time or access time.  If you want time of creation, feasibility will depend on the filesystem (eg, if the file system records that information at all; most common filesystems do not).

Comment: As William pointed out -  [birthtime](https://blog.marbu.eu/posts/2019-02-17-btime/) support in Linux is not that common.  The most common uses are `-ctime` (when the inode was changed) or `-mtime` (when the file was modified) as options to `find`.  If the filesystem supports birthtime and you have a suitable file to compare against you can have a look at the `newerXY` option.

Answer (score 0):

For find all PDF on your linux system with +30 days old and delete them you can use this command :

```
find / -name -ls -o -regex '.*\.pdf' -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;
```

The **/** is the path where recursively the command search PDF file.

The **-regex '.*.pdf'** is the regex for only match PDF file

The **-type f** only file

The **-mtime +30** match file with 30 days minimum old (delete too file which have 32 days old)

The **-exec rm {} ;** Execute the **rm** command with {} is the full file name found.